# Creating a Postal/Zip Code Boundary Look up Map

Tags: jquery, geolocation, gis, geospatial

How do I create a map that after you enter your postal or zipcode(if in US) it highlights the boundaries of that zip code with in a greater area?

I would like to pull from data globally. So you could enter a UK postal code or a US one for example, and it would still show the boundary highlighted.

I have limited experience in programming.

Cheers

Comment: What technology do you want to use? Have you conisdered [Leaflet R](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) o [tmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html) in R? Do you have the zipcode data?

Comment: The idea is i have a form, where you enter a zip code and the map identifies it to the left. I understand google maps can do this, but can I embed that into a website?

Comment: I havent considered those and will look into them

Comment: May be you have in mind something like [This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html)?

Comment: Yes something like that - but with my own data added.

Comment: Have the zip code entered query up the related data to to that zip code. Also have the zip code highlighted like google maps. How hard would this be to do?

Comment: Have you used R before? For R users, is usually easy to get familiar with Shiny. A background in web technology (HTML + CSS) is useful but not necessary.